# [ExpressJs]: Custom Error handler do not catch exceptions

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am creating a router with ExpressJs (using TypeScript) and thrown exceptions are not caught by my custom error handler, here is the code:

In `index.ts` file (which is the main):

```js
import express, { Express } from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import { config } from '~/utils/config';
import { NotFoundRoute } from '~/middlewares/NotFound';
import { ExceptionHandler } from '~/middlewares/ExceptionHandler';
import { usersRouter } from '~/controllers/users';

const app: Express = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.all('*', NotFoundRoute);
app.use(ExceptionHandler);

app.listen(config.port, () => console.log("API is running on port " + config.port));
```

The custom exception handler:

```js
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';

export const ExceptionHandler = (err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  if (res.headersSent)
    return next(err);

  if (err.status && err.message) {
    res.status(err.status).send({ error: err.message });
  } else
    return res.status(500).send({ message: "Internal Server Error" });
}
```

The router that is problematic (where `InternalServerError` is not caught by the above):

```js
import { Request, Response, Router } from 'express';
import { User } from '~/schemas/User';
import { InternalServerError } from '~/errors/InternalServerError';

const usersRouter = Router();

usersRouter.get('/', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const users = await User.find({});
    res.status(200).send(users);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({ message: "Failed to fetch users"});
  }
})

usersRouter.post('/register', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!email || !password)
      res.status(403).send({ message: "Bad Request"});
    const newUser = User.createUser({ email, password });
    await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).send(newUser);
  } catch (err) {
    throw new InternalServerError();
  }
})

export { usersRouter };
```

All my exception are not caught which means that it is not exception-related.
In the `index.ts` file, the `NotFoundRoute` throws an exception that is caught, so I guess it works on the file's context. How it is not working ? I suppose the router has a thrown exception that would be caught but it is not.

To remind the context, I am trying to force errors to happen to see if the error handling is correct. So in this case I forced

```js
newUser.save()
```

to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Express cannot handle `thrown` exceptions or `rejected` Promises. To tell express that there is an error you need to call the `next()` function instead of using `throw` or rejecting a Promise:

```
usersRouter.post('/register', async (req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!email || !password)
      res.status(403).send({ message: "Bad Request"});
    const newUser = User.createUser({ email, password });
    await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).send(newUser);
  } catch (err) {

    next(new InternalServerError()); // This is how you "throw" errors
                                     // in Express

  }
})
```

Note that express only expect you to call the function it passes as the **third** argument. The name of the argument is up to you. You can use words other than `next`:

```
usersRouter.post('/register', async (req: Request, res: Response, error: Function) => {
  try {

    /* some logic */

  } catch (err) {

    error(new InternalServerError());

  }
})
```

Though traditionally the name of the third argument is `next` and most javascript developers expect it to be that.

Comment: Well, it works but how does the exception thrown by `NotFoundRoute` is caught by the handler ? (look at `index.ts` file).

Comment: I don't know because you haven't show what NotFoundRoute is. My guess is that it does not throw an exception but instead call responds directly with `res.status(404)`

Comment: It makes sense that calling `next()` works but I am still trying to figure out why it works on the `NotFoundRoute`, thanks though

Comment: ```typescript

import { NotFoundException } from '~/errors/NotFound';

export const NotFoundRoute = () => {
  throw new NotFoundException();
}
```

Comment: And of course the exception contains a property `status` and `message` just as the `InternalServerError` exception that are set to 404 and a custom message

Answer (score 1):

Adding to slebetman's answer: You *can* throw errors that will be handled by the exception handler, but only in *synchronous* middleware. You can try it out:

```js
app.use("/sync", function(req, res) {
  throw "sync";
})
.use("/async", async function(req, res) {
  throw "async";
})
.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.end("Caught " + err);
});
```

Comment: That would explain why the the thrown exception of `NotFoundRoute` is caught then ?

Comment: Yes, because your `NotFoundRoute` is a synchronous function.