# Express middleware to conditionally change response result

Tags: express, middleware

What I want to achieve is when an express handler fails either by throwing an unhandled exception or returning an empty response like `undefined` or `[]`, I want the handler to return a predefined mock response rather than failing. This means my server never fails as it either returns the normal real data or predefined mock data.
Of course I will only turn this on in development environment and never in production.

I think a middleware is ideal because I don't want to pollute every handler logic by injecting the response check.

Is this possible with a middleware in express?
If not, what's a cleaner way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

The return value of a middleware handler is irrelevant, because a middleware handler is asynchronous by nature. It does one of three things:

- It completes the response by calling [`res.end(...)`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.end) or similar.
- It reports an error by calling `next(err)`.
- It delegates the decision to the next middleware by calling `next()`.

Errors can be caught with an additional [error-handling middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.error-handling), and exceptions can be converted into errors as discussed in [[ExpressJs]: Custom Error handler do not catch exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72393161/expressjs-custom-error-handler-do-not-catch-exceptions).

However, you cannot change a response after it has been sent. Moreover, you write

> an express handler fails ... by ... returning an empty response

but an empty response is not a failure. If you want to treat empty responses as failures, but only in production, I suggest that you handle them as special errors. Instead of responding with `res.json([])`, say, you write `next({emptyResponse: []})` and have special error-handling middleware *in development only* to handle these:

```js
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.emptyResponse) {
    console.error(err.emptyResponse);
    res.end("Mock response");
  } else next(err);  // delegate to the standard error handler
});
```

Perhaps there is a misconception what a response is. The server streams the response to the client, only the client can "get" the response in this sense. Responses cannot be passed between middlewares.

Comment: can I define a before middleware `foo` before the real handler,  inside `foo` it calls `next` to get a response and then check whether the response is success or failure. if it is 200 then just return it; otherwise return a mock response. This is probably not a standard middleware but more like a wrapper;  I think it does what's needed?

Comment: See the additional paragraph in my answer.

Comment: How about an `after` middleware that is after the normal handler? If the normal handler fails then call `next` which is the `after` middleware that returns the mock? Otherwise just bypass the `after` middleware? Guess the downside is I have to change every existing normal handler